# notepad++ reg expressions to swap two values

Tags: regex, notepad++

i'm trying to swap latitude and longitude values in notepad++ with regular expressions. i tried to search some guide on the web but i didn't understand how to do. i have a file in which there are: "longitude,latitude" and i want to get: "latitude,longitude" in each row

Example (with two rows):

```
   12.5164654350527,41.8919188281474
   12.5164650441393,41.891919097598

   becomes

   41.8919188281474,12.5164654350527
   41.891919097598,12.5164650441393
```

Which regular expression do i have to use?

Comment: What have you tried? I will give you some hints: 1) find out how to match a number with decimals. 2) Use capturing groups

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try with following regex:

```
(\d+\.\d+),(\d+\.\d+)
```

and replace it with:

```
\2,\1
```

Answer (score 3):

Search for:

```
([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?),([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)
```

Replace with:

```
\2,\1
```

This catches numbers like `1`, `1.1` but not `1.` or `.5`. My previous regexp `([0-9]+.?[0-9]*),([0-9]+.?[0-9]*)` would allow for `1.`.

Comment: Don't forget to escape the `.`, and be aware that this also matches `1.,2.` !

Comment: But it doesn't match `.1,.2`... Not sure if leading zeros are guaranteed - OP's question is a bit light on details.

Comment: You know if you're dissatisfied with your previous regex you can replace it, right? :)

Comment: @Robin, I know, I left it intentionally. If I wouldn't do that, above comments wouldn't make any sense and could be misleading.

Comment: @g_a_kowalski: I think things are pretty clear here so you don't need to worry about that. I usually find that posts whose core content is obvious at the first glance (more in [this spirit](http://bit.ly/RLR95J)?) usually get more exposure, but I might spend too much time thinking about formatting. Do what you want, already upvoted you :)

Comment: @Robin, thanks, I edited my answer according to your suggestion :-)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you place the cursor at the beginning of the file.

1. Hit `CTRL+H`.
2. Choose the `Replace` tab.
3. Select `Regular Expression` at the bottom.

   **Find:** `([\d.]+),([\d.]+)`
   **Replace:** `\2,\1`

Answer (score 0):

find what:

```
^([0-9]*\.[0-9]*),([0-9]*\.[0-9]*)$
```

replace with:

```
\2,\1
```

also, search mode should be set to regular expression

edit: escaped `.` as suggested in comments.

Comment: You need to escape the `.`

Comment: good point.  it did work without escaping the dot, but it's best to have it escaped.

Comment: Will inadvertently match `.,.` - not sure if there's a 100% useful solution without the REs getting unnecessarily complicated, though. Would require more info from OP...

Comment: changing the `*`s to `+` would help.  but if there are troublesome records in the data set, i'd be happy to revise my answer further if OP will add them to the example.